# How to sum random two numbers?

Tags: python, random

This is a tough question I got from my school for a beginner. The program asks to generate two random numbers between 1 to 10 and told to make the output of the sum in a separate function with two passed parameters. I managed to generate two random numbers but how to sum up that is a kinda new deal to me.

```
import random
randomlist = random.sample(range(1, 10), 2)
print randomlist
```

Comment: How would you sum two numbers with pen and paper?

Comment: I know how to sum two numbers with pen and paper but this is not a pen and a paper. It will generate two random numbers and then the sum will happen. So if you have any answer it would be good to help me .Thank :)

Comment: Sorry you are finding this difficult, but back in the day I didn't even have a computer and everything was done with pen and paper. I meant when doing maths you would write something like: `x + y = ?`. Have you tried something like this, but in python?

Comment: @quamrana sorry i think you misunderstood my saying ,yeah i have tried something like that and i am sorry later i will ask question after more researching done by myself :) dont be angry with me :D

Comment: If you are going to improve, then all is well. When you ask questions here then try and make an attempt at all the points. When you post code that is wrong then that makes it really clear where you have got to with your thought processes.

Comment: yes i will try to follow that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function and then return the output of the addition. A function which takes two arguments.

```
def addition(number1, number2):
    return number1 + number2
```

number1 and number2 are the 2 arguments. Since you already have 2 numbers in your list you can pass them like this.

```
print(addition(*randomlist))
```

The * unpacks the items in your list and passes them as seperate variables.

I would suggest doing some reading on python functions

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would do it:

```py
import random
randomlist = random.sample(range(1, 10), 2)
print (randomlist)

def get_sum (integer0, integer1):
    sum = integer0 + integer1
    return sum

print(str(get_sum(randomlist[0], randomlist[1])))
```

Comment: Does not do the assignment with a separate function.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your valuable time for helping me .I am new to python so please consider my any flaws or asking inability as honest mistake .

Comment: Still doesn't address the question correctly.  The spec said the function takes two arguments.  Also, the spec said that the function would do the output.  Finally, indentation matters in Python.

Comment: fair enough, not sure how indentation got messed up on my copy/paste.  I've fixed the function to have two arguments.